# How to test arm64 code without iPhone5S or iPad Air?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, arm64

I'm wondering is there any way to test how an app will work on arm64 without physical devices with arm64 support?

iPhone 64-bit simulator seems to compile code for intel processor architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are testing for compiler bugs, the simulator should behave in exactly the same way as the original hardware. There are bugs that are possible when going from 32 to 64 bit; these bugs will be visible on the simulator as well because it produces Intel 64-bit code for the 64-bit simulator.

If you need to test on an actual device, you'll have to buy or borrow one.

Comment: I've been reported about bugs on `arm64` architecture. Mb you aware about it, it's about different behaviour `va_list` on this architecture, on simulator `va_list` works fine.

Comment: I meant that as I already said in question, intel simulator does not works for me.